# How to check if a string is composed of commas only in java?

Tags: java, string

I have a string that it can contains commas, but not only commas.
For example:

- "," is wrong
- "hello, my dear" is right
- ",,,," is wrong
- ",,hello" is right

For this reason I don't think I can use regex. How could I test this situation avoiding simple comparison like this one?

```
myString.equals(",") || myString.equals(",,") || ....
```

Comment: Just count the amount of commas in the String and compare it the length of it. Then they are not equal, then there is more than just commas.

Comment: Seems like a pretty straightforward regex to me: `,*`, or maybe `,+` depending on how you want to treat the empty string.

Comment: Or you can scan the string and keep track of whether you see both a comma and a non-comma.

Comment: Actually, you can use regex. `string.matches(",+")` will do it for you. You just have to negate it using `!`.

Comment: Any way around `String.equals()` does not afford a viable solution.

Comment: You can use regex, but you have to also catch the possibility that the only comma is the last character in the string.

Comment: ",,hello" is right"  - I dont think so this is right Grammar. Please define more cases for better understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest solution, IMHO, would be to stream the characters, and check that they are all `','`:

```
boolean onlyCommas = myString.chars().allMatch(c -> c == ',');
```

Comment: I like this approach. Will probably perform faster than regex

Answer (score 2):

A regex is actually what you're looking for:

```
boolean result = myString.matches("^,+$");
```

`^` represents the beginning of the string, `$` represents the end of the string and `,+` matches only (and at least one) comma characters. This way you match any string that *only* consists of comma characters.

Comment: No need for `^` or `$` . `matches` always checks the entire String

Comment: Shouldn't you also negate this, since a comma-only string is "wrong" according to OP.

Comment: Regex is fine in general, but your suggested one is flawed.  There's no advantage to anchoring it, and you don't in any case catch the case where the only comma is the last character in the string.

Comment: @TheLostMind, not only that, but you don't need the entire string to match anyway.  `find()` without anchoring is just as good for this purpose.

Comment: @JohnBollinger But `find()` doesn't tell you if the String contains only commas?

Comment: @JohnBollinger - I don't quite understand what you are trying to say :). can you elaborate -  *and you don't in any case catch the case where the only comma is the last character in the string*

Comment: @JohnBollinger how does anchoring hurt? The regex distinquishes the two cases that were asked for and I don't understand how it is flawed. It might be too much due to String.matches() but flawed?!

Comment: @TheLostMind, I mean, you only need to know whether the string contains, anywhere inside, a comma next to a non-comma.  You don't need to match the whole string.  Granted, though, that's not what this particular regex is trying to do.

Comment: Based on `myString.equals(",") || myString.equals(",,") || ....` I believe the requirement is to match strings that *only* contain commas.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - But the OP's regex is still correct. It checks if the entire String contains only commas. You are stating another approach which will work, but that doesn't mean that this answer is wrong.

Comment: @TheLostMind, who said the answer was wrong?  Certainly not me.

Comment: @oschlueter - He is saying that we could check for a , followed by a "non-comma" character. Which is also correct

Comment: @oschlueter, if you read the question text and examples, you will see that the OP wants to determine not only whether the string contains non-commas, but also whether it contains at least one comma.  Your answer is useful in determining that, but not complete.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I don't see where it's specified that a valid string has to have *at least* one comma. The post is titled "How to check if a string is composed of commas only in java?" and the examples just happen to have at least one comma in all of them.

Comment: In fact, OP is clear in that requirement: "I have a string that _can_ contain commas". It's the first sentence. He speaks about "can contain commas". That means, the string can also contain no commas at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
String replacedString = someString.replace(",", "");
```

If it was made up of just commas the string will be empty afterwards.